# How to keep text aligned with the middle of a textarea?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<body>

This should be level with the middle of the box!
<textarea id="id" name="name" rows="9" cols="50">Text is in here!</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

[Picture of what this ends up looking like](http://gyazo.com/a62b9cadfb7732247917066da381d75c.png?1346011178).

How do I make it so that the text to the left of the box stays level with the middle of the box, even if it's being dragged around? Can it be done with CSS, or will it require Javascript?

Comment: You should show the relevant CSS. The code you posted will not end up looking like the screenshot you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set both the text and textarea to `vertical-align: middle`. Example HTML:

```css
.middletext {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#id {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <span class="middletext">This should be level with the middle of the box!</span>
  <textarea id="id" name="name" rows="9" cols="50">Text is in here!</textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

If you want to set a width/height on the text, add `display: inline-block` to the `.middletext` class.

Comment: After doing some more reading, I decided to forgo tables in favor of your vertical-align method. Works just how I wanted it to, thanks a lot! You too, @codingbiz, and everyone else who gave solutions!

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data. If you are making a standard form, tables do fit that mould.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way (if you want to avoid tables) is to float your label and set its line-height equal to textarea height:

See http://jsfiddle.net/pctVh/2

Comment: Middle, as in vertical middle, not center.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `vertical-align` property along with `display: table-cell;`. Here's an example, HTML:

```
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "text">
        I'm in the middle! Glee is awesome!
    </div>
    <textarea id="id" name="name" rows="9" cols="20">Text is in here!</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-row;    
}
.wrapper textarea {
    display: table-cell;
}
.text {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/aLecE/6/).

I hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

This does work

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td valign="center">This should be level with the middle of the box!</td>
   <td>
         <textarea cols="40" rows="20">Text is in here!</textarea>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```