# begin typing from middle of text area Not work for ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am creating some ionic3 small application.  I tried to create like as whats app status page. I added ionic text area for that. but text input cursor not in a  begin typing in middle. Does anyone know how to do that correctly?

**Html**

```html
<ion-content>
  <textarea #myInput id="myInput" rows="7" maxLength="300" (keyup)="resize()" [(ngModel)]="myStuff" text-center placeholder="Notifictaion here..."></textarea>
</ion-content>
```

**css.**

```
#myInput {
    width: calc(100%);
    border: 0;textAlignVertical: 'center';
    border-radius: 0; font-size: 2rem;
    background: #3e50b4; color: white;
  }
```

you can understand my issue look at my attached  image

**Issue**

[image]

**I want to like this**

[image]

Comment: probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133492/how-to-keep-text-aligned-with-the-middle-of-a-textarea

Comment: @SurajRao Sir.  tha is t not my issue. i want to text area value  put a middle

Comment: that is what the link suggests... can you specfiy how is it different?

Comment: ok sir .will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i do that , i put hsome padding for my css  `padding: 100px 10px 100px 10px;` now its work for me

**before**

```
#myInput {
    width: calc(100%);
    border: 0;textAlignVertical: 'center';
    border-radius: 0; font-size: 2rem;
    background: #3e50b4; color: white;
  }
```

**then**

```
#myInput {
    width: calc(100%);
    border: 0;textAlignVertical: 'center';
    border-radius: 0; font-size: 2rem;
    background: #3e50b4; color: white;
   padding: 100px 10px 100px 10px;
  }
```